# How to pass an empty string in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a chart for RBAC.

And one template is

```
...
rules:
{{- range $rule := .Values.rules }}
- apiGroups: {{ .apiGroupts }}
  resources: {{ .resources }}
  verbs: {{ .verbs }}
{{- end }}
```

In my values

```
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  ...
```

The rendered result is

```
- apiGroups: []
```

The problem is that helm ignores the empty string as a value. It causes problems with the resource Role because "" means the core group.

```
rules[0].apiGroups: Required value: resource rules must supply at least one api group
```

I tried the following. But it does not recognize the syntax

```
- apiGroups: {{ .apiGroups | default [""] }}
```

Comment: Should it be a string? `default \`[""]\``

Comment: You possibly should also check `toYaml` function (and `indent` filter may be?).

Answer (score 0):

Not answering for this exact use case but to the question in the title, which is how I got to this question. Answer is using the `hasKey` template function. The problem with `if` is that it considers empty string or `""` as `nil`.

Given:

values.yaml

```
string: foo
emptyString: ""
```

templates/test.yaml

```
{{- with .Values}}
{{- if .string }}
{{ printf "if string=%q" .string }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .emptyString }}
{{ printf "if emptyString=%q" .emptyString }}
{{- end }}
{{- if hasKey . "string" }}
{{ printf "haskey string=%q" .string }}
{{- end }}
{{- if hasKey . "emptyString" }}
{{ printf "haskey emptyString=%q" .emptyString }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Will return:

```
if string="foo"
haskey string="foo"
haskey emptyString=""
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to add a pipe with `quote` to allow empty strings

`- apiGroups: {{ .apiGroups | quote }}`

https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#quote-strings-dont-quote-integers